# SQL Server 2008, can I refer to a temporary table in a select statement within a udf?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

I'm trying to run a select query on a temporary table within a udf. I can't find documentation stating this isn't allowed, yet the below stored procedure won't compile when I change `tblDailyPricingAndVol` to `#dailyPricingAndVolBySymbol` (my temporary table of course. The temp table is created at a higher level (in a stored procedure before the stored procedure that uses this function) if that affects anything... thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
The udf is meant to just be a helper for the stored procedure that calls it.. I'm trying to query a temporary table with it due to the fact that it'll get called thousands of times each time it runs. The data that it retrieves and then aggregates is in a table with millions of rows. So I pare down the data into several hundred records, into the temporary table. This will speed the function up dramatically, even though it'll still take a fair bit of time to run.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.PricingVolDataAvailableToDateProvided
    (@Ticker nchar(10),
     @StartDate DATE,
     @NumberOfDaysBack int)
    RETURNS nchar(5)
AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result nchar(5)
    DECLARE @RecordCount int

    SET @RecordCount = (SELECT COUNT(TradeDate) AS Expr1
        FROM (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT TradeDate
           FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol WHERE (Symbol = @Ticker) AND (TradeDate IN
                 (SELECT TOP (@NumberOfDaysBack) CAST(TradingDate AS DATE) AS Expr1
                  FROM tblTradingDays
                  WHERE (TradingDate <= @StartDate)
                  ORDER BY TradingDate DESC))
                  ORDER BY TradeDate DESC) AS TempTable)

    IF @RecordCount = @NumberOfDaysBack
        SET @Result = 'True'
    ELSE
        SET @Result = 'False'

    RETURN @Result

    END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As been mentioned by other posters, you can't use a temporary table in an UDF. What you **can** do is pass a [User-Defined Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526.aspx) to your function.

> **User-Defined Table Types**
>
> In SQL Server 2008, a user-defined table type is a user-defined type
>   that represents the definition of a table structure. You can use a
>   user-defined table type to declare table-valued parameters for stored
>   procedures or functions, or to declare table variables that you want
>   to use in a batch or in the body of a stored procedure or function.

A quick fix for changing your code could be

```
CREATE TYPE DailyPricingAndVolBySymbolType AS TABLE (<Columns>)
DECLARE @DailyPricingAndVolBySymbol DailyPricingAndVolBySymbolType

INSERT INTO @DailyPricingAndVolBySymbol SELECT * FROM #DailyPricingAndVolBySymbol

ALTER FUNCTION dbo.PricingVolDataAvailableToDateProvided (
  @DailyPricingAndVolBySymbol DailyPricingAndVolBySymbolType READONLY
  @Ticker nchar(10),
  @StartDate DATE,
  @NumberOfDaysBack int
) ...
```

Comment: Thanks again... newbie follow- up question, do I create the table type in the stored procedure that creates the temp table?

Comment: @StatsViaCsh - I have never tried it but I doubt that would work. There is no harm in trying it though.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're out of luck. I created a quick function below and got an explicit compiler message that says you can't reference temp tables in a function.  I'm not sure why you would need to reference temp tables within a UDF, that's not really the spirit of UDF. Could you show how you were planning to call this UDF? Maybe we could help on that refactor.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Temp tables cannot be accessed from within a function. I suggest using a staging table instead. To better organize these in your DB you could create a schema called Staging, a table called Staging.dailyPricingAndVolBySymbol, and call that from your UDF.